# How to connect to a local server(in house server)?

Tags: networking, local

I am a noob when it comes to network.  Recently, I was trying to help a friend edit php code.  In his office, there is a computer running which he said is the server that hosts the site.  But he is not sure since the guy that build the site is unreachable now.  So, he gave me the password and username to this local server but no ip to me.  I have no idea how to connect to this "in house" server.

I see that there are several computers in the office and I tried to ssh to their LAN ip, ie. 1.1.1.1... to 1.1.1.10 something like that but none of the connection went through.
When I look up the ip of the website and put the ip into the browser, it actually goes to networksolutions.com.  So guys, do you think the source code can be found on networksolutions.com(which is what I think) or is there a way to try to connect to this "in house" server(I am not even sure whether there's anything in it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried attaching a monitor and keyboard to this server to determine what it is?

The IP of the site appears to be virtual hosted by Network Solutions. It is likely the server in the room is in fact not the server, instead that is handled by NetSol.

Comment: Yeah, I tried attaching a monitor to that machine, but nothing came up, I tried moving the mouse around, the screen is just black.  Even the fan of the motherboard is not running.  The cable is connected to a device that looks like a huge hard drive with its own fan.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the local ip range of the network which is normally either `10.*.*.*` or `192.168.*.*` or so you can use `nmap` to locate any servers quite quickly like: `nmap -vvv 192.168.0.*` which takes 5 seconds to find 4 end points

Comment: Yeah, the local ip all stars with 1.1.1.*, I tried nmap -vvv 1.1.1.0 and it saids:Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2010-12-09 09:06 EST
NSE: Loaded 0 scripts for scanning.
Initiating Ping Scan at 09:06
Scanning 1.1.1.0 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 09:06, 0.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Read data files from: /usr/share/nmap
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -PN
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.07 seconds

Comment: `nmap -vvv 1.1.1.0` only scans that one ip you need `nmap -vvv 1.1.1.*` for the range `1.1.1.0` to `1.1.1.255`